# FlatButton's left and right edges are not colorizing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a gradient colored flat button but left and right edges of the button are not getting colorized as the image. [image]

And here is my flatbutton codes:

```
return new Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40,
      child: RaisedButton(
        
        focusNode: buttonFocusNode,

        onPressed: ()  {},
         
       
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.purple],
            ),
            
          ),
        ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
```

It happens on both emulator and real device. My hyerarchy to button in build is : SafeArea->Scaffold->Container->Stack->Container->Column->Button. I tried to wrap it inside container, sizedbox, played with width but nothing helped. Any idea why this is happening and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `RaisedButton` adds padding for the child. You need to set the padding to `EdgeInsets.zero`.

#### Example

```
RaisedButton(
   padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

Comment: Yes, I thought padding will automotically wrap all the button. Thanks a lot, worked like a charm.

Comment: This solution has some shortcomings. Check my answer based on the new `ElevatedButton`. (`RaisedButton` is deprecated)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with an `ElevatedButton`:

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, //                                     <====== [2]
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0), // <====== [1]
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.purple],
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(
      'CLICK ME!',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 48.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

### Important point 1

Since you remove the `padding` on the button, remember to add it on the child `Container`. Otherwise, you'll have problems once you add some text:

[image]

### Important point 2

If you want rounded corners, remember to set the Clip Behavior of the button. Otherwise, you will not get your rounded corners:

[image]